# Why am i getting an overlad error when using .pushback on vector enclosed by a vector

Tags: c++, hash, stl, std, push-back

I'm trying to create a hash table with a vector inside a vector made of a struct. `v[1].push_back(value);` it's giving me an error:

```
error C2664: 'void std::vector<node,std::allocator<node>>::push_back(_Ty &&)': cannot convert argument 1 from 'int' to 'const _Ty &'
        with
        [
            _Ty=node
        ]
note: Reason: cannot convert from 'int' to 'const _Ty'
        with
        [
            _Ty=node
        ]
note: No constructor could take the source type, or constructor overload resolution was ambiguous
```

Here is my code:
    struct node {
    int data;

```
node() {
    data = 0;
}
};

class hashmap {
public:
vector<vector<struct node>> v;
vector<struct node> n;

hashmap() {
    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
        v.push_back(n);
    }
}


void insert(int key, int value) {
    int index = Hashfunction(key);
    v[1].push_back(value);

}

int Hashfunction(int key) {
    int index = key % v.size();
    return index;
}



};
```

Comment: Change ctor of node to be: `node(int d = 0) { data = d; }`. Now, you have no conversion from `int` to `node` structure.

Comment: @rafix07 event further, `node( int d = 0 ) : data { d } {}`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Always look at the full error message, modern compilers tend to be quite helpful. In this case the key information is: `cannot convert from 'int' to 'const _Ty' with _Ty=node` which if you swap out the type template gives `cannot convert from 'int' to 'const node'`. This isn't related to having nested vectors. You would see the same error with the following code:

```
struct node {
    int data;

    node() {
        data = 0;
    }
};

vector<struct node> n;
n.push_back(1);
```

The error is because the compiler has no way to convert from an `int` to a `node`. The fix is to provide a constructor which takes an `int`:

```
struct node {
    int data;

    node()
    : data(0)
    {
    }

    node(int value)
    : data(value)
    {
    }
};
```

Note the use of initialisers rather than assigning to the members in the constructor body, this produces more efficient code.

Ideally constructors taking a single argument should be marked `explicit` to help prevent issues like ambiguities:

```
struct node {
    int data;

    node()
    : data(0)
    {
    }

    explicit node(int value)
    : data(value)
    {
    }
};
```

Note you need to slightly change your `push_back` call to explicitly create a `node`:

```
v[1].push_back(node(value));
```

Or slightly more efficient and less typing:

```
v[1].emplace_back(value)
```

Comment: `: data { 0 }` `: data { value }` could be better to specify initialization explicitly .

Comment: @arnes no, makes no difference for `int`